# Use params within params when creating an Airflow operator

Tags: airflow

Here is an airflow operator example

```
t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='templated',
    params={'my_param': 'Parameter I passed in'},
    dag=dag,
)
```

Is that possible to use params in params, like this?

```
t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='templated',
    params={'my_param': 'Parameter I passed in',
            'my_param2': '{{ params.myparam }} again'},
    dag=dag,
)
```

Some of my params depend on others. Not sure the best way to do it.

Is this ok, if I use macro in params?

```
t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='templated',
    params={"epoch": "{{ next_execution_date.int_timestamp }}"},
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: you mean passing  `params` as a variable to the bash script?

Comment: params will pass as a variable to the bash script. In bash, if I do `echo {{ params.my_param }} {{ params.my_param2}}`. Will it be interpreted as `echo Parameter I passed in Parameter I passed in again`?